# Variable multiplication in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to multiply two variables through a batch file. The code is:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO OFF
SET /A res = 0
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,2) DO (
    FOR /L %%j IN (1,1,3) DO (
        SET /A res = %%i * %%j 
        ECHO Multiplying %%i and %%j
        ECHO %res%
        )
    )
```

The problem is that I always get 0 as a result. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's the output:

```
Multiplying 1 and 1
0
Multiplying 1 and 2
0
Multiplying 1 and 3
0
Multiplying 2 and 1
0
Multiplying 2 and 2
0
Multiplying 2 and 3
0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ! to expand the variable due to your delayed expansion setting:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO OFF
SET res = 0
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,2) DO (
    FOR /L %%j IN (1,1,3) DO (
        SET /A res = %%i * %%j 
        ECHO Multiplying %%i and %%j
        ECHO !res!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're outputting the result in the same block where you set it. Read up `help set` on delayed expansion. `cmd` expands `%variables%` when a command is *parsed* which is much earlier than when it's executed. As a side effect your `%res%` is replaced by zero.

You need

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the start and then use `!res!` instead of `%res%`.

Side note: Ditch the spaces around the `=` in your `set` calls. They work as you expect when using them with `/A` but won't otherwise.

Comment: Damn. I had the enabledelayedexpansion but didn't know about the !res! thing. Thank you!

Comment: Reading the documentation can be helpful sometimes ;-) Also sorry for not elaborating further, but I have explained this about 200 times by now, I guess.